# Does it make sense to subtract VaR from spot shocks?

Tags: risk, value-at-risk, risk-models

I have a model to compute the Event Risk (in dollars) from a shock to the spot price of an asset. I also have the 10-day VaR PnL for the same assets returns. These two numbers are then aggregated to find the total risk in dollars:

$$\sqrt{\text{VaR}^2 + \text{Event Risk}^2 + 2\rho_{\text{VaR, Event Risk}} \times \text{VaR} \times \text{Event Risk}}$$

(assuming some correlation $\rho_{\text{VaR, Event Risk}}$ between the VaR and Event Risk model)

The idea of subtracting the VaR from the Event Risk **before they are aggregated as above**, is that the event risk should be computed just for shocks **not captured by the VaR** to avoid double counting when computing the total risk. This makes the total risk in the formula above smaller.

Example:

```
Current Scheme

VaR    Event Risk    Total Risk (rho=0.2)
10     22            25.92



Proposed VaR subtraction

VaR    Event Risk    Event Risk - VaR    Total Risk (rho=0.2)
10     22            12                  17.09
```

Does it make sense to do this or is there any literature on the matter? Is there some statistical way we could show that the subtraction is valid?

EDIT: The event risk model essentially takes a max (shock up) / min (shock down) between market and macro implied indicators. The indicators do not consider historical returns as a VaR calculation would.

Comment: what you are not mentioning is how the event risk number comes about. i think the answer will depend on that

Comment: then i struggle a little with the notion of aggregating two things with entirely different underlying concepts